# Connect to mysql in CLI - distinguish db name and password

Tags: mysql

I am trying the following mysql command:

```
zcat ***.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p dbname
```

Maybe the question applies equally to the following, simpler command:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname
```

You can find this kind of snippet all over the internet, and it usually works. It should prompt you for the db user's password (in this case, the db root pw), and then use "dbname" as the database name. Only today it did NOT ask me for the root pw, and instead just said

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I assume that in this case mysql thought that "dbname" is the password. I just don't understand why in the usual case it understands that "dbname" is the database name.

I have also seen this variation:

```
mysql -u root -pthepassword dbname
```

Here the interesting thing is that -u is followed by a space, but -p is not.

The question: How does mysql distinguish the dbname from the password?

Comment: it doesn't. it's always required no space after -p. `-phunter42` is a password, `-p hunter42` is "prompt for password, use database hunter42"

Comment: Ok, so then the "access denied" in the first case must have had another reason.

Comment: And I assume this is just a mysql-specific oddity, right?

Comment: I always used it exactly this way, but always found it illogical/inconsistent.

Comment: there's always the long-form options: `--password=foo`